# Paypal : Sandbox facilitator business account not getting credited in Paypal

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I have created a facilitator account in Sandbox paypal. I am using auth and capture for the payments. I have also created test accounts test-buyer-1@xxxx.com

Currently I have 2 facilitator account. One is default(say fac@xxx.com) and the other one(say fac-1@xxx.com) has been created by me.

I am using the username, password, Signature and AppId(for adaptive payments) from fac-1@xxx.com.

I am successfully able to capture the account from the buyer's account and I logged into www.sandbox.paypal.com using my buyer's account(test-buyer-1@xxxx.com) to see that the buyer's account has been debited. 
However, when I login using my created facilitator account(fac-1@xxx.com), I cannot see any amount being credited into the account. Similarly, I can't see anything in the fac@xxx.com account as well.

One thing I observed that in the details of one of the transaction for test-buyer-1@xxxx.com account, I see something funny:
Business Name:
facilitator account's Test Store 
Email:
jaypatel512-facilitator@hotmail.com

[image: Snapshot]

Can someone please help me understand why I'm not able to see the credited amount in the Business account?

I am using paypal's REST SDK for Java.

Comment: can you let me know the transaction ID from the buyer account? I will check for more info.

Comment: I was able to get this resolved. Apparently, the clientId and secretId were messed up. I created a new facilitator account and was able to proceed with the correct transaction